# Getting a very slow startup on Ubuntu 20. Seems to be stuck around the stage where the Gnome screen appears

Tags: ubuntu, boot, performance, gnome

My system is:

- Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on a dedicated SSD (no virtual machine)
- Intel® Core™ i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz × 8  with 31.3 GiB

I use the default setting BIOS (ASUS motherboard). I did not do any overclock etc.

Here are the steps when I start Ubuntu:

1. **Very Slow**: Waiting a very long time (approximately 2 min 20 sec) with a Ubuntu Gnome screen. See screenshot.
2. Enter username + password and submit.
3. **Very Fast**: Once username + password submited wait a bit until to use the system.

Many posts suggest to enter a `systemd-analyze blame`, but as you see below the process that takes the longest last 6 second and the next ones approx 1 second. So I am not expert but I guess hat this analysis is more to analyze issues from step 2 to 3. But my issue seems to be more between step 1 and 2. In addition if I sum up all the system analysis blame I even not end up to 1 min wheras step 1 to 2 takes approx 2 minutes and 20 seconds.

```
6.482s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                  
1.050s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1502.mount
1.050s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-36.mount 
1.005s snap-whatsdesk-19.mount                
 937ms snap-core18-1885.mount                 
 934ms snap-core18-1932.mount                 
 932ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-128.mount
 848ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-60.mount 
 756ms snap-gtk2\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-9.mount 
etc
```

I have tried to use a totally different SSD drive with windows 10 and it took me approx 7 seconds to get windows system running.

I started with Ubuntu 16 LTS then 18 LTS and now 20 LTS. So it is not a fresh start with Ubuntu 20. But if possible I want to avoid to try to install Ubuntu from scratch…

Once started the system is very reactive and very fast (no issues). Issue is slow startup.

[image]

I have also removed the Ubuntu Gnome background in step 1(by removing the split splach in the grub config) and I see that what takes 1 minute and 30 seconds I get this message:

```
A start job is running for /dev/disk/by-uuid/fc18b..........
```

I have now something to investigate further.

Comment: Could it be that v. 20 is still downloading drivers at startup (it shouldn't, of course)? Try booting with no network connection, neither Ethernet nor WiFi, and see if it fails or if it takes as long.

Comment: I dont think is the problem , i am using it for more than 2 month since i switched to ubuntu 20

Comment: It may be normal. My Ubuntu 20.04 system (VM on a very fast SSD) takes 60 to 90 seconds to a login screen. Log in. Then 15 to second to "ready".  So it may be what you are loading and running.

Comment: @John I am not convinced that it is  normal. before  my ubuntu 20 update, i.e. with ubuntu 18, it look a couple of second with same hardware!

Comment: I had Ubuntu 18.04 on the same setup here (upgraded to V20 in place). There was not a large slow down for Ubuntu 20.  Normal load of startup items. My Kali VM has similar startup characteristics.

Comment: Yes John, so I think in your case ubuntu 20 reacts normally like probably for many many users. In my case it is not the case (unfortunately). And I am stuck about how to solve that issue...

Answer (score 0):

Issue was related to this error.

```
A start job is running for /dev/disk/by-uuid/fc18b..........
```

Seems the ID linux swap was not the one in the fstab file.

I solved it with this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h23oQr8Nvqc

Now it takes approx 20sec to run the system instead of 2min20.

Answer (score 0):

If you upgraded to ubuntu 20 from ubuntu 18:

1. Check ownership of /:  >stat /
2. If you get something like:
   Uid: (1000/ your_username) Gid: (1000/ your_username)
   then
3. Change ownership of /:  >chown root:root /
4. Check ownership of / again. You should get
   Uid: (0/ root) Gid: (0/ root)
5. reboot

My Dell XPS13 Boot time went from about three minutes down to 23.758 s.